# Usage of "Hey you!"

Tags: sentence-usage

My understanding is that we can use "Hey you!" to call someone whom we don't know. Can I use "Hey, you!" to call someone when I'm very angry at him?

Basically, my question is whether "Hey, you!" can be used in context of anger?

Comment: Yes, it can be. An alternative might be, "Listen, you..." Also, I wouldn't use either one of those unless I didn't know the other person's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hey, you!" is impolite, so it's most appropriate in situations where politeness is not called for.  That makes it well suited for addressing someone in anger.

Of course, you can still be polite when you're angry, and you can of course be even less polite, but the answer to your question is **yes**, this phrase can be used when you're angry.

Comment: I'd never think of using "Hey you!" in anything except anger.

Comment: With a rather different tone of voice, the informal but friendly "Hey, you!  Gimme a hug!" is possible.

Comment: True. I hadn't thought of ironic usage. In my mind, it would be a fairly specific situation among close friends or family, and meant to bridge an awkward gap -- perhaps after an argument or a long absence. I wouldn't use that device myself, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can exclaim "Hey, you!" to express anger or to get someone's attention. "You" is not required as shouting "hey" towards someone repeatedly to get their attention gets the same point across.

There are alternative acceptable usages of "Hey, you." For example, two companions may greet one another in this manner (not shouting, of course).

Comment: Some years ago, I had a Chinese friend named Yu. Seeing him at some distance away at a shopping mall, and trying to get his attention, I (perhaps unfoolishly) yelled out, "Hey, Yu!" I think a dozen people or so turned around to see what my problem was.

Comment: @J.R. That's so funny. :D